# Condition on Script Status?

Tags: systemd

I have a SystemD unit which formats a filesystem in the cloud.

According to [the systemd unit documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), there exist many different `Condition*` arguments that units accept to determine whether they should run or not. I need to be able to determine if `/dev/xvdb` is formatted as ext4, and the only way I've found to do that is to do something like this:

```
if ! blkid -t TYPE=ext4 | grep xvdb >/dev/null; then
    mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
fi
```

While I can drop this bash script somewhere on the filesystem, it would seem more intuitive if SystemD could execute a *script* to determine whether a service should conditionally start.

Is there a workaround for this which doesn't involve dropping a file on the filesystem?

The only two choices I see are:

1. Drop a bash script on the filesystem that always returns 0 and only formats if necessary.
2. Using `ExecStartPost`, `touch` a file on the filesystem to serve as a tag and then `ConditionPathExists=!/path`.

Is there a way to have SystemD invoke a script to determine whether it should execute a unit?

Answer (score 3):

With systemd v243 and later (post-[#12933](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/12933)) you could use [`ExecCondition`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=):

```
ExecCondition=sh -c '! blkid -t TYPE=ext4 | grep -q xvdb'
```

Be aware of how systemd interprets [command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) and [special executable prefixes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=), which can be useful (or surprising) in conditions.

Comment: There seems to be a difference between `ExecCondition` and `ConditionPathExists` in the failure case.  If I have a service that Requires foo.service, and foo.service is skipped because of a `Condition*` being false, then service that required it is still started.  But if foo.service is skipped because of `ExecCondition`, then the service that requires it is not started: `failed with result 'dependency'`

Comment: @TrentP I think you are referring to [systemd/systemd#18207](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18207), which was fixed by [systemd/systemd#18211](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/18211).  So that would only occur in systemd v243-v247?

Comment: You're right, I've tested with v247, so it would have that bug.  I didn't understand from the documentation why there should be a difference.  Looks like the answer was there isn't one, it was a bug.